# Native support for extend class?

Tags: javascript

Is there any support for JavaScript nowadays for classical inheritance?

```
function A extends B() {} 
function B() {}
```

I know about all other tweaks and twerks, and not interested in any of them.

I am wondering if there is native support nowadays. I remember reading about it, but can't not google it, because all the tweaks and twerks are coming up.

Hope you understand!

Comment: No; learn how to use the prototype and get over it.

Comment: Twerking's a thing in code, now? O.o

Comment: make a prototyped language works like a classical OO language, is the same of make a classical OO language works like a prototyped language... you only can do it with workarounds... but any problem can be solved with the 2 ways, using natively resourses of language. You can't do it with prototype inheritance?

Comment: @LuanCastro I don't believe that is true. I think it is possible, since the prototyped way A.prototype = new B() already does this. 

Plus, you can use B.apply(this, argument) from inside of A, at the top to get the right behavior. However, if you are building an API you want to simplify this further. I was hoping they had by now.

Comment: @MoJS `A.prototype = new B();` it's a simulation of classical inheritance, you're forcing the language to be a other paradigm. The language is designed without class concept, this make the objects only receive behavior of another object, can't be called inheritance if you're thinking in classical inheritance. Only a philosophical concept.

Comment: Your suggestion/example is flawed though. As I commented on the other answer, the example you show assumes only one instance of A, a singleton. As soon as you create several instances, you will in some cases be sharing the same B instance. 

Here is an example: 

http://paste.ofcode.org/ygDNpV5ZMsnU2YP6MWX3BB

Answer (score 2):

Not as such just yet, no; the current way of doing it is something like this:

```
function A() { }
A.prototype = new B();
```

And, to try to ease the pain, a number of JavaScript libraries try to provide class-defining methods for you that make it just a little bit more like Java or C. I only know a tiny fraction of them, so I won't offer comparisons, but you may just have to find whichever one works best for you.

Comment: Yeah, no problems. Thanks for providing your input though!

Comment: By the way, the example you show assumes only one instance of A, a singleton. As soon as you create several instances, you will in some cases be sharing the same B instance

Comment: @MoJS I don't believe that's true. Just like a company makes "a prototype" of their new product, and then factory-creates thousands of them, the prototype of A is not the same object as the constructed one. It's sort of just a convenient way to ensure each 'A' gets all of B's default functions and properties.

Comment: It is true, people usually fail to mention that fact though. Here is an example: 

http://paste.ofcode.org/ygDNpV5ZMsnU2YP6MWX3BB